# Is there a way to control the FileList order in Mobile Safari?

Tags: reactjs, mobile-safari, filelist

In React I am using this element to get multiple images:

```
  const onAcquirePhotos = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      console.log(event.target.files);
    }
  }

  <input type={'file'} accept={'image/jpeg'} id={'choosePhoto'} onChange={onAcquirePhotos} multiple />
```

The images I receive in event.target.files (the FileList object) are not in a consistent order as they are in other browsers (I want the files/images to load in by the order in which they are in the photo library). The "name" and "lastModified" fields are also not consistent. Is there something I can do here? or is this just Safari being Safari?

Edit: I added the function that gets the files. I select the same images on every attempt, but the console.log does not print them in the same order for each attempt. The goal is to get them in the order that they appear in the file system/photo library like in other browsers.

Comment: You could sort the result yourself. I'm not aware of any html attributes that would tell Safari to sort the input files

Comment: @Dominik The issue is how would I sort it? What fields would I use? I tried lastModified, but this does not work in mobile Safari.

Comment: Share what you got so far and what you expect the output to be and we may be able to help you

Comment: I added some more context @Dominik